# Single Sign on Not working on Jboss

Tags: java, security, authentication, jboss

I am trying for a single sign on in Jboss server. I modified the standalone.xml file with the like below.

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
            <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
            <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
                <alias name="localhost"/>
                <sso domain="localhost" reauthenticate="false"/>
            </virtual-server>
```

```
<security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">
    <authentication>
      <login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional">
<module-option name="password-stacking"  value="useFirstPass"/>
      </login-module>
      <login-module code="RealmUsersRoles" flag="required">
<module-option name="usersProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/application-users.properties"/>
<module-option name="rolesProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/application-roles.properties"/>
<module-option name="realm" value="ApplicationRealm"/>
<module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
      </login-module>
     </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

I modified my jboss-web.xml like below

```
    <jboss-web>
    <security-domain>java:/jaas/other </security-domain>
          <valve>
        <class-name>org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn</class-name>
    </valve>
</jboss-web>
```

My web.xml is like below.

```
    <servlet>
<servlet-name>secret</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.tomcat.demo.SalaryServer</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>secret</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>SecretProtection</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/servlet/SalaryServer</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/servlet/secret</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
<auth-constraint>
<role-name>admin</role-name>
</auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
<auth-method>
FORM
<!-- BASIC, DIGEST, FORM, CLIENT-CERT  -->
</auth-method>
<form-login-config>
<!--  only useful for FORM  -->
<form-login-page>/loginpage.html</form-login-page>
<form-error-page>/errorpage.html</form-error-page>
</form-login-config>
</login-config>
<security-role>
<role-name>admin</role-name>
</security-role>
</web-app>
```

But still the single sign on is not working. I have to sign in to each app separately. Please help me .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enabling SSO in AS7 is really simple. Just use this JBoss CLI command:

```
/subsystem=web/virtual-server=default-host/sso=configuration:add(reauthenticate="false")
```

It results in following line in `virtual-server` element under `web` subsystem:

```xml
<sso reauthenticate="false"/>
```

Remove also the `jboss-web.xml` from your deployments - you don't need it. The valve entry is wrong at all (the `sso` part in `standalone.xml` replaces it) - it was only valid in old JBoss AS (5 for instance). The `other` security domain is the default one - no need to have it specified in the deployment configuration.

One more thing, remove the `http-method` elements from the `security-contraints` section in `web.xml`. Otherwise all other HTTP methods **will not be secured**.

The correct form is:

```xml
<web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>SecretProtection</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/SalaryServer</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/secret</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
</web-resource-collection>
```